# windows 8.1 display monitor keeps refresh very fast and cannot do any change in dialogue

Tags: windows-8.1, display, multiple-monitors, refresh-rate

in my Thinkpad Lenovo laptop with windows 8.1 installed,i want to change my monitor positioning or resolution but after starting to drag my secondary monitor or resolution drop-down, because the window is refreshing very fast , focus is lost and any action does not work!!

i uninstalled my driver and even in the safe mode but this issue still exists.

it is the same in Intel Control panel and also windows Monitor setting

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

using http://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/ solved my problem

UltraMon is a utility for multi-monitor systems, designed to increase productivity and unlock the full potential of multiple monitors.

- efficiently move windows and maximize windows across the desktop
- manage more applications with the Smart Taskbar control application
- positioning with UltraMon Shortcuts multi-monitor support for desktop
- wallpapers and screen savers mirror your main monitor to secondary
- monitors for a presentation